# Run Junit test for various values of a list

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

I have created a Junit Test where the Test class has some variables like:
private final String version="0.25.1"
And when I run tests it compares the files related to this version.
There is an init() method too.
Currently how I am testing it for another version by changing the value of the version
manually to "0.24.1" and "0.24.0" so that I could check test results for all of these versions.
Is there a way to specify a list of versions and then run the tests for each version and see the results?
It's a spring boot project.
Here is a minimal code for the Junit Test that I have written:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK, classes = Application.class)
    @AutoConfigureMockMvc
    @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-local.yml")
    @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
    class MDServiceTest {
        @Autowired
        private MDService MDService;
        private List<File> MDFiles;
        private final String version = "0.24.1";
        private final String MDType="WLCR";
    
        @BeforeAll
        public void init() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            MDFiles = MDService.generateMDFiles(version, MDType);
        }
    
        @Test
        void testMetaAttributeFile() throws IOException {
            File MDAttribFile = MDFiles.get(0);
            String filePath = String.format("src/%s/%s_%s.csv", version, MDType,version);
            File expectedMDAttribFile = new File(filePath);
            Assert.assertTrue(Utility.compareCsvFiles(expectedMDAttribFile, MDAttribFile));
        }
    
      @Test
        void testMetaFile() throws IOException {
            File MDAttribFile = MDFiles.get(1);
                       .
                       .
                       .

        }
    
        @Test
        void testZip() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            List<File> MDFiles = MDService.generateMDFiles("0.24.1", "WLCR");
            String zipFileName = "test.zip";
            File file = Utility.zipIt(MDFiles, zipFileName);
            Assert.assertEquals(zipFileName, file.getName());
        }
    
    }
```

I need to modify this so that it runs automatically for all version numbers. It could be that to use parameterizedTest I will have to modify this class because the init method also uses the version and @ParameterziedTest probably cannot be applied on it.

Comment: you might want to look at [parameterized tests](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests)

Comment: can it be used on the init() method that's annotated with @BeforeAll?

Comment: If these are your only tests, then is that method really necessary? Inside `testZip` you generate the files again anyway, so the only method that uses the result of `init` is `testMetaAttributeFile`. You might as well remove the field completely and turn it into a local variable like in `testZip`.

Comment: @RobSpoor I added one more dummy method. There are actually in total 4 methods like testXYXFile() , all of them use the result of init() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameterized testing. It runs same test on different parameters.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

    public class YourTestClass {
    
        private YourClassToTest yourClassToTest;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        yourClassToTest = new YourClassToTest();
    }
        @ParameterizedTest
        @MethodSource("versions")
        public void testWithDifferentVersions(String version) {
            // Set the version in your test class based on the parameter
            yourClassToTest.setVersion(version);
            
            // Your test assertions
        }
    
        static Stream<String> versions() {
            return Stream.of("0.25.1", "0.24.1", "0.24.0");
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: In my case the init() method `new YourClassToTest();` The class new YourClassToTest(); also needs the version to be instantiated

Comment: I think then you can avoid the init function and create the object in the test method it self , It is not a good practice but it serves the purpose I guess

Answer (score 0):

This approach defines a constructor for a parametrized test class that can accept parameters that correspond to the input values for parameterized tests.  A factory method is used to create test instances with different sets of input values (in this case, a list of version strings)

When you run the tests, an instance of `MDServiceTest` for each input value provided by the data method is created, and the constructor will initialize `version` for each instance.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
class MDServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MDService MDService;
    private List<File> MDFiles;
    private static final String version;
    private List<File> MDFiles;
    private final String MDType="WLCR";

    public MDServiceTest(String version){
        this.version = version;
        MDFiles = MDService.generateMDFiles(version, MDType);
    }
    @Test
    void testMetaAttributeFile() throws IOException {
        File MDAttribFile = MDFiles.get(0);
        String filePath = String.format("src/%s/%s_%s.csv", version, MDType,version);
        File expectedMDAttribFile = new File(filePath);
        Assert.assertTrue(Utility.compareCsvFiles(expectedMDAttribFile, MDAttribFile));
    }

    @Test
    void testMetaFile() throws IOException {
        File MDAttribFile = MDFiles.get(1);
                       .
                       .
                       .

    }

    @Test
    void testZip() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        List<File> MDFiles = MDService.generateMDFiles("0.24.1", "WLCR");
        String zipFileName = "test.zip";
        File file = Utility.zipIt(MDFiles, zipFileName);
        Assert.assertEquals(zipFileName, file.getName());
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                {"0.24.1"},
                {"0.25.1"}
        });
    }
```